# Developing theme locally using stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a reason I need to install stencil CLI framework and supporting javascript etc... rather than just download a theme and edit it with notepad, then re-upload it?

Is seems that this has been made overly complicated

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of using the Stencil CLI is that you can *test your work* locally, so you can be sure you haven't broken anything. If you just want to make a small edit, then rather than downloading and uploading, try editing files within the Control Panel.  Go to Storefront->My Themes->Customize, and then at the bottom, click Edit Theme Files. This way you can make a small edit and have the ability to do a preview (so again, you test your work before changing your live store).

Comment: hello I see. But Bigcommerce allows you to upload a theme without activating it and also allows you to do live previews with your content with that inactive theme. So you can still preview it without testing on your live store. So there is 2 ways to tackle this and no need to install all that.